# I installed a Facebook Standard Event Pixel "Lead" and its returning as "SuccessCall"?

Tags: laravel, facebook, pixel, lead

I installed a Standard Event Pixel "Lead" and its returning as "SuccessCall" when instead I am looking for the "Lead" event?

There is no reference to 'SuccessCall" in the entire website code but it is recognising it as if I physically installed "SuccessCall" as an event.

I implement the "Lead" Facebook Pixel after an implementation of an old Facebook Conversion Tracking Pixel that I am not sure if I should remove or not (at the risk of losing something of value). Could that be the reason why I am not getting the results I desire?

The code is below;

```
<!-- Old Facebook Conversion Code for All Life Leads - Thank You Page -->
    <script>(function() {
            var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
            if (!_fbq.loaded) {
                var fbds = document.createElement('script');
                fbds.async = true;
                fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
                _fbq.loaded = true;
            }
        })();
        window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
        window._fbq.push(['track', '*************', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
    </script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=*************&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '*************');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');

    fbq('track', 'Lead');

</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=*************&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: I don’t think you should embed two different pixel script versions on the same page, possible that is leading to trouble. The single track call the first block performs, should be easily doable using the new code as well if necessary. (If it _always_ tracks a static value of `0.00`, it probably doesn’t make the most sense to begin with.) Get the FB Pixel Helper Chrome extension if you don’t have it already, it can help debugging what is going on on the page live.